# (Linux) Formatting variables into columns printf

Tags: linux, bash, printf

I'm trying to show a file name, size and type in 3 columns. The data just isn't showing correctly and I just can't see why.

Here's my code:

```
    fileName=$(ls -a ~/dirname)
    fileSize=$(find ~/dirname/* -printf '%s\n';)
    fileType=$(find ~/dirname/* | xargs file |  awk '{print $3}')

    printf " ----------------------------------------------------------\n"
    printf "%15s %15s %15s\n" "Name" "Size" "Type"
    printf " ----------------------------------------------------------\n"
    printf "%15s  %15s  %15s\n" "$fileName" "$fileSize" "$fileType"
```

The output is showing like:
(Output as an image just to avoid stackoverflows formatting)

[image: Output Screenshot]

Comment: Each variable contains the information for 3 files, but you're treating them like just one file.

Comment: Ah. I thought I could display it all. Would I have to use a 'for loop' for each file in the directory and print it one at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with a little bit of help from Barmar identifying what I was doing wrong:

```
    for fileName in $(ls -a ~/dirname/*);
    do
            fileSize=$(stat --printf="%s" "$fileName")
            fileType=$(file "$fileName" | awk '{print $3}')
            printf "%15s  %15s  %15s\n" $(basename "$fileName") "$fileSize" "$fileType"
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables each hold the information for all the files, but you're printing them at one time, not separating them. Also, the order of files returned by `find` is not the same as the order of `ls` (it sorts them lexicographically).

You need to loop over the files and print each one on a different line:

```
printf "%15s %15s %15s\n" "Name" "Size" "Type"
printf " ----------------------------------------------------------\n"
ls -a ~/dirname | while read -r fileName
do
    fileSize=$(stat --format=%s "$fileName")
    fileType=$(file "$fileName" | awk '{print $3}')
    printf "%15s  %15s  %15s\n" "$fileName" "$fileSize" "$fileType"
done
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, %z is giving me an error: 
stat: cannot read file system information for ‘%z’: No such file or directory
stat: cannot read file system information for ‘test1’: No such file or directory

Even though these files do exist.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the OS X `stat` command, which is different from Linux.

Comment: Not a problem! It all made sense once you gave me the idea.